# Acumatica Import Scenario - Import AR Invoices - Out of Balance Error

Tags: import, acumatica

When attempting an AR Invoice/Memo import scenario I get the following:

Error: Inserting 'AR Invoice/Memo' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors. The document is out of the balance. Migrated balance cannot be less than zero or greater than the document amount.

I have migration mode on. I have a Balance that I'm importing.

2019 R2 Build 19.206.0036

Thanks for any suggestions.